# Saving returned json data to NSDictionary or NSArray to be displayed in TableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm pulling JSON data and am trying to figure out how to save each key thats being looped through into a dictionary to be displayed in my TableView.

My code:

```
-(void)fetchedDetailData:(NSData *)responseData {

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    NSDictionary* placeDetails = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
    NSString *taxiName = [placeDetails objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *taxiPhoneNumber = [placeDetails objectForKey:@"international_phone_number"];

    parsedDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [parsedDict setValue:taxiName forKey:@"name"];
    [parsedDict setValue:taxiPhoneNumber forKey:@"international_phone_number"];
    NSLog(@"%@", parsedDict);

}
```

Seems the log outputs this:

```
2014-01-12 10:38:59.864 B[720:70b] {
    "international_phone_number" = "+1 508-760-0000";
    name = "All Points Taxi";
}
2014-01-12 10:38:59.928 B[720:70b] {
    "international_phone_number" = "+1 508-564-7500";
    name = "Bourne Bridge 24HR Taxi";
}
2014-01-12 10:38:59.936 B[720:70b] {
    "international_phone_number" = "+1 508-524-8818";
    name = "Barnstable Taxi and Limo";
}
2014-01-12 10:38:59.950 B[720:70b] {
    "international_phone_number" = "+1 508-221-1804";
    name = "Cape & Islands Air Taxi";
}
2014-01-12 10:39:00.114 B[720:70b] {
    "international_phone_number" = "+1 508-775-5555";
    name = "Town Taxi of Cape Cod Inc";
}
```

Looks like it's overwriting each one, rather then adding each one. This method is being called in a for loop for each reference obtained from Google Places. Not sure where I'm going wrong exactly, just trying to save each phone number and name for each taxi into a NSDictionary to be displayed in Tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSDictionary` will overwrite your value for the same key like `name` in your `parsedDict`. so you need an array to save your parse data.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *parsedList; 

if(!parsedList){
    parsedList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
NSMutableDictionary *parsedDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parsedDict setValue:taxiName forKey:@"name"];
[parsedDict setValue:taxiPhoneNumber forKey:@"international_phone_number"];
[self.parsedList addObject:parsedDict];
NSLog(@"%@", self.parsedList);
```

Comment: Ok great, now that I got the array how would I go about obtaining each item for indexPath.row to display in cells?

I've tried cell.taxiName = [self.ParsedList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; but that I know wouldnt work considering it wouldnt be pulling  whats under the name for that IndexPath.row

Comment: Actually I think I fixed it, just set a NSDictionary to equal the objectAtIndex for array, then pulled out the objectForKey for name, thanks so much